# How to search, display and edit results on same page using Rails 4.2.4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on an application to maintain Information about cars using Rails.

I am unable to figure out solution to the following problem, probably because I am quite new to Rails.The application maintains information about car number,color and owner. User should be able to search by all these three attributes(selected from a dropdown list). When user hits the search button results should be displayed on the same page(retaining the search box). The result table will have all these attributes along with edit button, user can use that to change the owner in-place(the owner field becomes editable when user hit the edit button).

Is it a good idea to create separate controller actions(and views) for each search option? If I do so I will have to probably duplicate the code to display result in a table and editing logic.

If I place all of these on same view and try to edit owner, how to reflect the change on the page immediately?

Any other thoughts on how actions and views can be arranged in order to accomplish this are welcome.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Using AJAX with JQuery or Javascript you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a good idea to create separate controller actions(and views) for each search option? ]

No.

You need to read up about [**MVC** (`Model View Controller`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). Your "view" logic should be handled in your controllers, data logic handled by models & views used to output the data.

---

> `User` should be able to search by all these three attributes(selected from a dropdown list)

This is confusing; I would class a "search" as a way for me type text into a searchbox (text field), and have the results appear somewhere. What you're suggesting is probably *filtering*.

To give you an overall pattern, here's what I'd do:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :cars #-> url.com/cars

#app/controllers/cars_controller.rb
class CarsController < ApplicationController 
  def index
    @cars = Car.all
    @filtered = params[:search] ? @cars : @cars.search(params[:search], params[:options])
  end
end

#app/models/car.rb
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"
  scope :search, ->(search, options) { where("#{options.each {|o| puts "#{eval(o)}: #{eval(search)}" } }") }
end

#app/views/cars/index.html.erb
<% form_tag cars_path do %>
  <% %i(name color owner).each do |x| %>
    <%= select_tag :x, options_from_collection_for_select(@cars, "id", "name") %>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag "Filter" %>
<% end %>

<% @filters.each do |car| %>
  <%= car.number %>
  <%= car.color %>
  <%= car.owner.name %>
<% end %>
```

---

> If I place all of these on same view and try to edit owner, how to reflect the change on the page immediately

You'd need to use a combination of a modal pop-over and [`ajax`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

The modal pop-over will load the "edit" form from the server, and the ajax will submit the form to the server. You'd then be able to render the changes as per the ajax `response` without refreshing.

[Great resource here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBxVN7U1Qsk).

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for the answer. I tried above code and it throws me an error. 'syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting '}' ...("#{options.each {|o| eval(o) = eval(search) } }") }'.

Comment: Are you around now? I've not tested that line, it would be better to go into chat for it.

Comment: HI Richard, I am around now. Which group do we use for chatting?